# OutputWriter Java or Android

Tags: java, android, io, outputstream

I want to write data to an output file and save it on a mobile device or on a computer harddrive. I am able to get my code below to work, but have to create the directory in one step and then create the file in another. Is there a more effective way to code having to create an non-existing directory before writing a file there?

Thanks

```
StringBuilder Path = new StringBuilder();
    Path.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

    String filename = "test.txt";
    String test_text = "Date, Item, Quantity, Description,";
    File file = new File(Path.toString()+"/" +"Test Folder2/");
    file.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream file_os = null;
    try {
        File file2 = new File(Path.toString()+"/" +"Test Folder2", filename);
        file_os = new FileOutputStream(file2);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(file_os);

        try {
            osw.write(test_text);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        try {
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(QuizSettingsActivity.this, Path.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    };
```

Comment: As long as the directory does not exist, I think that you will have to create the directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String FILENAME = "test";
String string = "Date, Item, Quantity, Description,";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

For more detail on saving file on external storage follow the link mentioned below:.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html